# Error when running python file on my Raspberry Pi 4b in Thonny

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, raspberry-pi4

I am making a remote viewable camera with my Raspberry Pi 4b. I am following this tutorial:
https://youtu.be/zfBHD4v8hD0?t=705

I am 11:45 into the tutorial, but when I click the run button, I get the following error:

```
RuntimeError: module compiled against API version 0xf but this version of numpy is 0xd
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/pi/pi-camera-stream-flask/main.py", line 7, in <module>
from camera import VideoCamera
File "/home/pi/pi-camera-stream-flask/camera.py", line 5, in <module>
import cv2 as cv
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/cv2/__init__.py", line 181, in <module>
bootstrap()
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/cv2/__init__.py", line 153, in bootstrap
native_module = importlib.import_module("cv2")
File "/usr/lib/python3.9/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
ImportError: numpy.core.multiarray failed to import
```

I'm new to RPI, and I have no idea what this error means, or how to fix it.

I tried running

```
sudo apt-get install VideoCamera
```

and

```
sudo apt-get install camera
```

But it says that it cannot find the file.

EDIT:
I ran `pip install numpy --upgrade` as suggested by `userid42`
And now I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/pi/pi-camera-stream-flask/main.py", line 7, in <module>
from camera import VideoCamera
File "/home/pi/pi-camera-stream-flask/camera.py", line 6, in 
<module>
from imutils.video.pivideostream import PiVideoStream
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'imutils'
```

EDIT:
Thanks to `userid42`
running the following fixed it:

```
pip install numpy --upgrade
pip install imutils
```

Now when I manually run the script in Thonny, it works, and I am able to view the camera live from any device that is connected to the same WIFI network.

**Now I am trying to have the script run automatically when my RPI 4b is turned on**.

I tried the method shown in the video, and also the first two methods here:
https://www.dexterindustries.com/howto/run-a-program-on-your-raspberry-pi-at-startup/

All three of these methods return the same error I was having to begin with. This is weird because it works fine when I run it manually, but it gives the error when it runs automatically (on startup).

Comment: The problem is related to NumPy. I suggest you reinstall packages or create a virtual environment to clear out effects of other packages.

Comment: This is a side point, but you should use "apt" instead of "apt-get", its just quicker to type

Answer (score 1):

"Runtimeerror" is complaining about the version of numpy.

Try the following:

```
pip install numpy --upgrade
```

Comment: I ran this, and now I get a different error. See my original post.

Comment: The new error: "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'imutils'" is mentioning that it cannot find the module "imutils". You need to install it.

Try:
pip install imutils